# Can I search existing IAM policies for a specific action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In AWS IAM is there a way, either by scripting or in the web console, to find which existing policies contain a given action?

For example, I want to allow role `myRole` to have access to the [DescribeTags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTags.html) action on all of my EC2 instances. I know I can create my own policy with an appropriate rule, but would like to use an existing Amazon policy if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old post, but it may help someone...  Despite what others have said, you can do this. It just requires a bit of scripting.

You can do the following with the AWS CLI.

1. Get the ARNs of the policies and store in the `policies_arn` array.

   `mapfile -t policies_arn < <(aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[*].[Arn]' --output text)`
2. Get the VersionIds for each policy and store in the `policies_ver` array.

   `mapfile -t policies_ver < <(aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[*].[DefaultVersionId]' --output text)`
3. Use a for loop to loop through each policy and store the policy document in `policies.txt`

   `for (( i=0; i<${#policies_arn[@]}; i++ )); do echo ${policies_arn[i]} >> policies.txt && aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn ${policies_arn[i]} --version-id ${policies_ver[i]} --output json >> policies.txt; done`
4. Open up `policies.txt` in a text editor and search for your action.

Note: Depending on your CLI configuration, you may or may not need the `--output text` parameter. However, the output must be text (not JSON) in order for this to work.

From there, you can turn that into a `.sh` shell script easily enough.

Sample Output:

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/DenyAllAccess
{
    "PolicyVersion": {
        "CreateDate": "2016-12-06T18:40:51Z",
        "VersionId": "v1",
        "Document": {
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "*",
                    "Effect": "Deny",
                    "Resource": "*"
                }
            ],
            "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "IsDefaultVersion": true
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: In step 3 above you use policies.txt and ~/policies.txt which works fine if you're in ~ but creates two files in different places otherwise.  Thanks for the useful utility though, very helpful.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on my understanding of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128660/447862 the important thing is to get the JSON from the default version of each policy. Since my machine does not have `mapfile` I opted to use Python.

```py
import boto3, json, sys

iam = boto3.client('iam')
policy_arn = sys.argv[1]
policy_name = policy_arn.split('/')[-1]

version = iam.get_policy(PolicyArn=policy_arn)['Policy']['DefaultVersionId']
policy_version = iam.get_policy_version(PolicyArn=policy_arn, VersionId=version)
policy_document = policy_version['PolicyVersion']['Document']

with open(f"{policy_name}.json", 'w') as outfile:
  outfile.write(json.dumps(policy_document, indent=2))
  outfile.write('\n')
```

Saving this as `aws-iam-policy-dump.py`, now I can write each policy document to its own file and search as much as I want.

```sh
aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[*].Arn' --output text > policy-arns.txt
for arn in $(cat policy-arns.txt); do
  python aws-iam-policy-dump.py $arn
done
```

This could probably go faster by doing everything in Python, but this hybrid approach is good enough for me.

Comment: Good enough indeed! thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

As I've searched for and found this very question and set of answers over the years, here's the plain `bash` (no `jq` required) command I use to produce a list of IAM policy names and their associated actions:

```bash
$ aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[*].[PolicyName, Arn, DefaultVersionId]' --output text |
    while read NAME ARN VER; do
      echo "$NAME $(aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn=$ARN --version-id=$VER --query 'PolicyVersion.Document.Statement[*].Action[]' --output text | tr '\t' ' ')"
    done > policies.txt
```

It takes a while to run, but then I can quickly grep through the output to find the existing policies I can reuse.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[*].[Arn, DefaultVersionId]' | jq -rc '.[] | join(" ")' | xargs -l bash -c 'aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn=$0 --version-id=$1 --query="{\"$0\": PolicyVersion.Document.Statement[*].[Action, NotAction][][]}"' | jq -c | grep YOUR_POLICY_ACTION_HERE
```

1. This basically captures all the Arns and Versions in the single call
2. Then joins the output into a single space-separated string
3. This string is then sent to another bash process via `xargs` where the ARN and VersionId are passed in as separate parameters to `get-policy-version`
4. The result of this is combined with the ARN into a single line
5. Lines are grepped for your pleasure with the search action you're looking for.

I came across this question looking for a way to find existing policies that may contain specific actions. The command will run in O(n) time based on the number of policies since a separate call is made for every policy you have.

I couldn't figure out how to get `.contains()` working properly in the last `--query` to allow aws to filter rather than grep.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure python version of @amacleod's response:

```
# based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270609/can-i-search-existing-iam-policies-for-a-specific-action
#          https://www.learnaws.org/2021/05/12/aws-iam-boto3-guide/

import boto3, json, sys

iam = boto3.client('iam')


def write_policy(policy_arn):

    # policy_arn = sys.argv[1]
    policy_name = policy_arn.split('/')[-1]

    version = iam.get_policy(PolicyArn=policy_arn)['Policy']['DefaultVersionId']
    policy_version = iam.get_policy_version(PolicyArn=policy_arn, VersionId=version)
    policy_document = policy_version['PolicyVersion']['Document']

    with open(f"{policy_name}.json", 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(policy_document, indent=2))
        outfile.write('\n')

def list_policies():
    paginator = iam.get_paginator('list_policies')
    for response in paginator.paginate(Scope="Local"):
        for policy in response["Policies"]:
            print(f"Policy Name: {policy['PolicyName']} ARN: {policy['Arn']}")
            write_policy(policy['Arn'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_policies()
```